# Remove trailing white space between verbatim and caption in a figure

Tags: verbatim

How can I remove or control the vertical whitespace between the verbatim figure and the caption attached to it. [image]

Here is my code right now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{verbatim}
        A0001 12 500 7500 12-May-2020 12:33:59
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 28 -1716 0 I
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 7 2029 0 II
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -21 3745 0 III
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -17 3680 0 aVR
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 24 -2664 0 aVL
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -7 -1499 0 aVF
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -290 390 0 V1
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -204 157 0 V2
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -96 -2555 0 V3
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -112 49 0 V4
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -596 -321 0 V5
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -16 -3112 0 V6
        #Age: 74
        #Sex: Male
        #Dx: 59118001
        #Rx: Unknown
        #Hx: Unknown
        #Sx: Unknown
    \end{verbatim}
    \caption{Sample Header File (A0001.hea)}
    \label{txt:hea}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: what is the full complete code? I see only a fragment.

Comment: @Sebastiano i updated the code in the question to include the full complete code

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to load `fancyvrb` and use `BVerbatim` for two reasons:

1. the environment doesn't add space above and below;
2. you can get centering without trying to indent “by eye“.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{verbatim}
        A0001 12 500 7500 12-May-2020 12:33:59
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 28 -1716 0 I
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 7 2029 0 II
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -21 3745 0 III
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -17 3680 0 aVR
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 24 -2664 0 aVL
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -7 -1499 0 aVF
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -290 390 0 V1
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -204 157 0 V2
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -96 -2555 0 V3
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -112 49 0 V4
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -596 -321 0 V5
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -16 -3112 0 V6
        #Age: 74
        #Sex: Male
        #Dx: 59118001
        #Rx: Unknown
        #Hx: Unknown
        #Sx: Unknown
    \end{verbatim}
    \caption{Sample Header File (A0001.hea)}
    \label{txt:hea}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here I also (locally) set `\abovedisplayskip` to zero, but I'd avoid it.

[image]

Without setting `\abovedisplayskip`:

[image]

Don't forget the `p` placement option for floats so large.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\vspace*{-10mm}` before `\caption` did the job for me!

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{verbatim}
        A0001 12 500 7500 12-May-2020 12:33:59
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 28 -1716 0 I
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 7 2029 0 II
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -21 3745 0 III
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -17 3680 0 aVR
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 24 -2664 0 aVL
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -7 -1499 0 aVF
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -290 390 0 V1
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -204 157 0 V2
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -96 -2555 0 V3
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -112 49 0 V4
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -596 -321 0 V5
        A0001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -16 -3112 0 V6
        #Age: 74
        #Sex: Male
        #Dx: 59118001
        #Rx: Unknown
        #Hx: Unknown
        #Sx: Unknown
    \end{verbatim}
    \vspace*{-10mm}
    \caption{Sample Header File (A0001.hea)}
    \label{txt:hea}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```